# Probability - Defective product

Tags: probability, independence

A company sends 30% of its product to Client A and 70% to Client B. Client A reports that 5% of the products it received are defective, whereas Client B reports that 4% of products received are defective. The defective products are returned back to the company.

What is the probability that a product is sent to Client A and is defective?

---

Is my calculation correct?

Required Probability

= P(product sent to Client A) * P(product is defective)

= 0.3 * (0.05 * 0.3 + 0.04 * 0.7) = 0.0129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that the item is sent to A, $B$ be the event that the product is sent to B, and $D$ be the event that the product is defective.  We are given $$\begin{align}
\Pr(A)&=.3\\
\Pr(B)&=.7\\
\Pr(D|A)&=.05\\
\Pr(D|B)&=.04
\end{align}$$

Now, $$\Pr(A\cap D)=\Pr(D|A)\Pr(A)=.05\cdot.3=.015$$

You have computed $\Pr(D)\Pr(A)$ which assumes that $A$ and $D$ are independent.  This cannot be the case; A gets a higher percentage of defective items than B does.

Comment: Thanks! Another following up question with the same context: What is the probability of a returned defective product coming from client B?

I have $$ \frac{0.04\cdot0.7} {0.04\cdot0.7+0.05\cdot0.3} = \frac{28}{43}$$